# Does someone get punished for unknowingly committing a sin or unknowingly hurting a person?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, sin, mussar-ethics, morality

Does someone get punished for unknowingly committing a sin or unknowingly hurting a person? Please provide sources, thanks.

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9D_%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%93_%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D

Comment: There is a huge range of "unknowing", depending on the circumstances and how preventable it was.

Comment: @Shalom True. Do you know of any example discussed in a rabbinic source(s)?

Answer (score 3):

We have a LOT of laws about this, depending on the situation, so I'd call this far beyond "ethics" or "philosophy."

If someone doesn't maintain their equipment properly and it causes a death, the punishment is exile. That one's spelled out in Deuteronomy. If someone forgot it was Sabbath and worked, they had to bring a sin offering when there was a Temple. (If they violated a rabbinic commandment by mistake, they should just study more and move on.) Per the link above, my obligation to prevent monetary damage to another covers just about any reasonable outcome -- if I decide to lie down and sleep six inches from someone's iPhone, then I roll over in my sleep and break it, I have to pay for the damage.

I am not, however, liable, if I went to sleep in my own empty bed, then someone put the iPhone next to me, then I rolled over.

So there are a ton of different cases here, depending on what kind of damage we're discussing (sin against G-d, or another person? Death? Torts? Slander?) , and what type of "unknowing" we're discussing (on the spectrum from "gross negligence/willful blindness" to "complete freak accident and thus deemed out of one's control.")

See for example Maimonides summarizing the manslaughter cases (they're described in the Talmud) in his [Laws of the Murderer and Preservation of Life, Chapter 6](https://%20https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Murderer_and_the_Preservation_of_Life.6.2?lang=bi):

> There are three categories of unintentional killers.  There is a
> person who kills unintentionally, without at all knowing that this
> will be the consequence of his actions...  There is a person who kills
> unintentionally, whose acts resemble those caused by forces beyond his
> control - i.e., that the death will be caused by an extraordinary
> phenomenon that does not commonly occur.... There is a person who
> kills unintentionally, whose acts resemble those willfully perpetrated - e.g., they involve negligence or that care should have been taken with regard to a certain factor and it was not.